# Can't type a "}" in PhpStorm

Tags: php, editor, phpstorm

I have an AZERTY keyboard, and my version of PhpStorm is : 2016.2 (Last version). I DID NOT have this issue with the previous version I got of PhpStorm.

How I discovered this issue? I'm currently learning web development and I was trying to Edit some templates when you create a new file but it seems that I can't even type into the editor itself...

Just so you know, in azerty keyboard, the default shortcut to type `}` is :
<kbd>ALTGR</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> (2 keys after the 0) and for the opening curly braces it's <kbd>ALTGR</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> (4)

Anyone got an idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Keymap, there is a Find Shortcut icon on the top right. Click it and press the same combination that you're trying to use for `}` sign. Remove the found shortcuts and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works !
(First question here, Do I have to close the thread or something ? )

Comment: @MarkusLaire Thanks !